# Flask for to have result as variable

Tags: python, flask

I have below form which selects the data and redirects to the page `user_data`

[image]

It selects the date and redirects to another page.
Am able to get the data using `request.form['Period']` method in python.
But this is not getting called in form action `<form action = "/user_data/{{period}}" method="POST">` period variable is empty resulting in **Not Found** error.

Is there a way to select a value and pass it into a same form

```
<form action = "/user_data/{{period}}" method="POST">
    <label for = "Period" id = "Period">Period</label>
    <input list="User_Listing_Period" id ="User_Lst_Period" name = "Period">
        <datalist id = "User_data_Period">
            {% for row in user_dat_filter %}
            <option name = "User_Dat_Period" value = "{{row[0]}}"></option>
            {% endfor %}
        </datalist>

    <div class="submit">
        <label for = "Submit" id = "Submit"></label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: If I understand what you're asking correctly, you want to amend the action url based on a onchange element event from within the form? You're going to need to do that in js.

If I've totally misunderstood then you might want to try `{{request.form.get('period')}}` but bare in mind its case sensative and you've wrote 'Period' and 'period'

Comment: as value of `User_Listing_Period` will be a dynamic value that will change at user selection (browser), so we need javascript for rescue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two options here:

1. let form direct to url `/user_data`, and based on the `Period` value renders the page i.e it renders the data for that month.
2. as value is based on user selection, JS can be utilized.

```
<html>
    <body>
<form action = "/user_data/{{period}}" method="POST" id="myForm">
    <label for = "Period" id = "Period">Period</label>
    <input list="User_Listing_Period" id ="User_Lst_Period" name = "Period">
        <datalist id = "User_Listing_Period">
          <!-- I commented this, so can check in HTML, you can go with your code
            {% for row in user_dat_filter %} -->
            <option name = "User_Dat_Period" value = "Aug22"></option>
            <option name = "User_Dat_Period" value = "Sep22"></option>
            <option name = "User_Dat_Period" value = "Oct222"></option>
               <!-- {% endfor %} -->
        </datalist>
    <div class="submit">
        <label for = "Submit" id = "Submit"></label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        const myform= document.getElementById("myForm")//identify the form
        // add a listener to myform
        myform.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault(); //block default submit
            const selectedOption=document.getElementById("User_Lst_Period")
            let value = selectedOption.value
            document.location.href='/user_data/' + value //redirect to value selected by user


        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```